# Git Workflow and Multi Environment - how to approach

Tags: git, multi-environment

I'd like to be able to use git version control with Craft. Is this possible and if it is what is the best approach to ensure that all files/assets and the database are properly synced across local, staging and production servers?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/10/whats-the-best-practice-for-handling-data-migration-and-organization-across-dev? Or is there something different about this question?

Comment: Somewhat related to http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/13/whats-the-best-practice-for-upgrading-a-versioned-craft-site?rq=1 as well.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Matt has a point, this is similar to [What's the best practice for handling data migration and organization across development environments?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/10/whats-the-best-practice-for-handling-data-migration-and-organization-across-dev), but that question focuses mainly on how to handle the database (definitely see those answers).

More generally speaking...

**Multi-Environment Config**

Set yourself up with [Multi-Environment Configs](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/multi-environment-configs) in both `craft/config/general.php` and `craft/config/db.php` so that you don't have to be updating path settings every time you migrate data between environments.

Be sure to set some [Environment-Specific Variables](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/multi-environment-configs#environment-specific-variables) for the site URL and server path for each environment. That way you can use those variables in the control panel settings (the Site URL setting in the *Setting → System → General* and Assets paths in *Settings → Assets → Your asset settings*).

Here is a sample `general.php` file

```
return array(

    '*' => array(
        'omitScriptNameInUrls' => true,
        'usePathInfo'=> true,
        'cpTrigger' => 'example-admin',
        'allowAutoUpdates' => false,
    ),

    'example.dev' => array(
        'devMode' => true,
        'useCompressedJs' => false,
        'allowAutoUpdates' => true,
        'environmentVariables' => array(
            'siteUrl' => 'http://example.dev/',
            'sitePath' => '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/example/html/',
        ),
    ),

    'staging.example.com' => array(
        'environmentVariables' => array(
            'siteUrl' => 'http://staging.example.com/',
            'sitePath' => '/var/www/vhosts/staging.example.com/html/',
        ),
    ),

);
```

And an example `db.php` file

```
return array(

    '*' => array(
        'tablePrefix'   => 'craft',
    ),

    'example.dev' => array(
        'server'        => 'localhost',
        'user'          => 'root',
        'password'      => 'root',
        'database'      => 'example_dev',
    ),

    'staging.example.com' => array(
        'server'        => 'localhost',
        'user'          => 'example_staging',
        'password'      => '********************',
        'database'      => 'example_staging',
    ),

);
```

For more on Multi-Environment Configs see [Multi-Environment Workflows](http://straightupcraft.com/learn-craft-cms/multi-environment-workflows) on Straight Up Craft

**Version control with Git**

You can definitely use Git. I version everything except for user file uploads and `/craft/storage` and it works great.

My master `.gitignore` file in the root of my project looks like (specific to my setup, YMMV)

```
.DS_Store

# Node/Sass
node_modules
html/css/public/main.css.map

# Config
dandelion.yml
sftp-config.json
craft/config/db.php
```

Then in each directory I want to ignore the contents of (craft storage and user uploads) I put a `.gitignore` file with...

```
# Ignore everything
*

# But not this file
!.gitignore
```

And as Matt pointed out in his other comment on your question, do see the answers on the related question [What's the best practice for upgrading a versioned Craft site?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/13/whats-the-best-practice-for-upgrading-a-versioned-craft-site)

Comment: You might as well add your .gitignore for posterity, since you've already added lovely multi-environment examples for the general and db configs. :)

Comment: How would I create templates for each of environments? `templates/staging/`?

Comment: You could have different branches in your git repo, one for each environment. Then deploy the staging branch to staging, the production branch to production, etc.

Comment: I probably misunderstood your question, Dominik. If Craft had a "path to templates" config setting then you could set that per environment, but I don't think it does.