# Correct way to set up development and production environments for Craft?

Tags: multi-environment

I'm setting up a new site using Craft and would like to know what's the best way to manage dev and production environments? For instance, keeping entries/fields/ and control panels configurations sane across both environments?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd recommend you take a look at the excellent existing threads on this:

- [Git Workflow and Multi Environment - how to approach](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/62/480)
- [What's the best practice for handling data migration and organization across development environments?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/10/whats-the-best-practice-for-handling-data-migration-and-organization-across-dev)

as well as the official documentation on [Multi-Environment Configs](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/multi-environment-configs)