# Why is Craft extremely slow when using a shared, external database?

Tags: performance, multi-environment, workflow

Every now and then I work in developer teams where we all use our local development environment to work on the code, but share the same database on a remote server (like discussed [here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/16380/recommended-workflow-when-developing-new-websites) etc.).

Most of the time this will kill Crafts performance big time on our local machines. Requests take up to 30 seconds in the Control Panel and in the front-end as well.

Does anyone else encounter the same behavior and/or has an idea how to improve that? The logs don’t explain much.

```
Time:   25.85331s
(index):3505 Memory: 25,723Kb
(index):3506 Total Queries: 287
...
```

The site on the remote server is snappy like you would expect it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My suggestion would be to do what is outlined in [Database & Asset Syncing Between Environments in Craft CMS](https://nystudio107.com/blog/database-asset-syncing-between-environments-in-craft-cms)

It's a little bit of logistical organization coupled with some scripts to do the asset/db synchronization.

It's going to be much, much faster than working with a remote db... and safer, too.

Comment: Thanks, will dig into the article in detail. Meanwhile I gathered more information on why those delays are happening. The reason is that Craft makes 200+ requests to the database... synchronously. So syncing databases and things like that really seem to be the only solution.