# Update fields structure from local to production

Tags: field, sections, deployment

How can I change fields/sections structure locally while having a live site and then upload the new structure, without wiping the production site?
In Wordpress ACF you can just Sync the fields structure, here it seems I need to close down the website for development?!

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of similar questions with good discussion on this:

[What's the best practice for handling data migration and organization across development environments?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/10/whats-the-best-practice-for-handling-data-migration-and-organization-across-dev/16)

[Recommended workflow when developing new websites](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/16380/recommended-workflow-when-developing-new-websites/16388)

[What's the best practice for upgrading a versioned Craft site?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/13/whats-the-best-practice-for-upgrading-a-versioned-craft-site)

Ultimately, we want to building something in core to help manage this and the upcoming Craft 3 has taken a step in that direction with [Content Migrations](https://craftcms.com/news/craft-3-content-migrations).

Comment: none of them offer a simple solution for uploading only the fields structure..

Answer (score 1):

You may find Sprout's [Import plugin](https://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/craft-plugins/import) useful in this regard.

Comment: It sais it supports all the data types except Fields. But thats exactly what I need, to sync the fields structure! not the data/content of Entries.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [The Architect plugin](https://github.com/Pennebaker/craftcms-thearchitect). This allows you to export selected attributes (e.g. fields, field layouts, sections, entry types, asset sources, transforms, globals, users and user groups) as a JSON file and import them into another site/environment.

It works very well for exactly the use case you describe: migrating the changes in content structure, not content, between environments.